# Seekbar for accounting transaction.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-seek

Hey I am making an official purpose app which conclude business transaction.

I want a ***Bar or SeekBar*** view which shows Income or Expense of company like this

- **Red** for if expense Exceeds
- **Green** for if Income Gained

[image]

Hopefully We have this type of customview in many apps.

Please Help me out with this..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**progress_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#00FF00" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Code:**

```
 SeekBar mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    mSeekBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_bar));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive what you want by using this light weight library. The good part about this is that you can easily customize it according to your requirement.

[image]

All you have to do is three xml files... [Check this out....](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/)

Hope this helps.